# How to smoothly transition between two images in a image component?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I have a state machine responsible for transitioning between different images, corresponding to player actions. I want to make the image a part of UI, but my main question is how do I transition between two images.Will using Lerp work in this situation? For reference I want to transition it like in powerpoint animation or windows image slideshow.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the effect you are trying to achieve?  If you are just talking about changing the image, you can just swap out the sprite.

Comment: Well, yes I've considered this option, but simply changing the sprite just isn't good enough, I'm talking more like a powerpoint fade or jump animation, preferably in an image component, I've considered DoTween, but I don't know whether it can smoothly change sprites within an image object.

Comment: No, an image component draws just one image at a time. You'd need two such components overlaid to do a cross-fade between them, or a custom shader that samples multiple images and does some type of transition in its math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest non-programer way to do this would be to use an animation to animate the transparency between two image components.